# Updating post meta for checkbox

Tags: posts, metabox, post-meta

```
  <div class="vp-field vp-checkbox vp-checked-field vp-meta-single" data-vp-type="vp-checkbox" id="_custom_meta[category][]">
<div class="label">
     <label>Categories</label>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <div class="input">
       <label>
          <input class="vp-input" type="checkbox" name="_custom_meta[category][]" value="star">
         <span></span>star</label>
      <label>
       <input class="vp-input" type="checkbox" name="_custom_meta[category][]" value="triangle">
       <span></span>triangle</label>
     <label>
      <input class="vp-input" type="checkbox" name="_custom_meta[category][]" value="square">
      <span></span>square
     </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>'
```

I am trying to update the post meta checkboxes, but the below is not working. Any suggestions what i am doing wrong.

```
 $features[0] = "star";
 $features[1] = "triangle";
 $features[2] = "square";

update_post_meta($post_id, "category",$features);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so probably the meta data is saved correctly, now we are going to retrieve it.

I'm not sure where and how you're adding this code, it looks like a metabox?

The checkboxes aren't magicly getting checked, you need to add some logic to it.

First we need to have a closer look how you save the checkbox data.
We want to save to the DB which checkboxes are checked.

This array:

```
$features = array();
$features[0] = "star";
$features[1] = "triangle";
$features[2] = "square";
```

Is not going to tell us which categories are checked.

We want to save the array like this:

```
$features = array();
$features['star'] = 1; // checked
$features['square'] = 0; // not checked
$features['triangle'] = 1; // checked
```

---

Above the checkbox HTML you need to get the features data (post_meta) from the DB.

Add this above the html:

```
<?php
global $post;
$features = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'category', true );
?>
```

When you want to check a checkbox you need to add the attribute `checked="checked"` to it.
We only want to do this if the features array from the DB is telling us to do so.
You can achieve this with this checkbox html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" id="checkbox_id" value="triangle" <?php echo (isset($features['triangle']) && $features['triangle']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
```

This:

```
<?php echo (isset($features['triangle']) && $features['triangle']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>
```

Checks if the array key (triangle) is present in the `$features` array and if the value is set to 1 (or any positive value). If yes, it outputs `checked="checked"`, if not, it does nothing.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: I am using vafpress framework(metaboxes). I will not be able to use <?php echo (isset($features['triangle'].....) as suggested because it is in the WP dashboard that I want to see the check marks. I am auto updating the post content using update_post_meta and particular for checkboxes I am not seeing the checkmarks are marked checked in WP dashboard. Rest of the text and text area content gets updated in the WP dashboard.

Comment: Simply said. If you can't add the checked="checked" and vafpress (never heard of it) also does not. Then you're stuck. It has to be one or the other. Contact vafpress to help you further. I can't do anything more for you at this point.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I will dig a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$features[0] = "star";
$features[1] = "triangle";
$features[2] = "square";

update_post_meta($post_id, 'category', $features);
```

Is fine, it will only fail if the `$post_id` is not found.
I'm assuming you want to save custom categories, not real WP taxonomies.

Do you have the debug log activated? Does it tell you anything?

---

**Activate debug log.**

1. [Download and activate a log viewer.](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-log-viewer/)
2. Open wp-config.php (located in WP root folder), and change the line:

   define( "WP_DEBUG", false );

into

```
define( "WP_DEBUG", true );// just toggle this line to false to turn off
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    define( "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY", false );
    define( "WP_DEBUG_LOG", true );
    @ini_set( "display_errors", 0 );
    define( "SCRIPT_DEBUG", true );
}
```

You can now view error logs. Disable logging when you are done!

---

**Working with the debug log**
If (for example) you want to check the `$post_id` that is being used, you can add the following right below the `update_post_meta()`:

```
error_log('The post id is: '.$post_id);
```

To check an array i always use:

```
error_log('The features array is: <pre>'.print_r($features,true).'</pre>');
```

---

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: I know it not the issue with post id, as other text fields are getting updated. where do I check error log?

Comment: follow the 2 steps i mentioned @ **Activate debug log**.

Comment: yep, I did that. I activated the plugin and edited the wp-config.php

Comment: ok, now you can view the debug log. Go to WP admin --> settings --> debug log. Maybe the log viewer is located somewhere else in the wp admin menu, look for it, it has to be there. I use my own log viewer.

Comment: btw, are you absolutely certain the post_meta is not saved to the database?

Comment: I am not seeing the check marks in the WP dashboard.

Comment: Ok, so you probably don't have a problem with saving the meta_data, you have a problem with retrieving and setting this saved data. See my new answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the last parameter (`$prev`) the `update_post_meta` to false, this enable you to insert new values to the `meta_key`. You can also check if the value is not already in the array before updating. Something like this.

```
// Get post met first
// false because we want to return all the values 
// saved in the meta key 'category'
$oldValues = get_post_meta($post_ID, "category", false);
foreach($features as $feature){
// Check if value is there, otherwise add it
  if (in_array($feature, $oldValues)){
    continue;
  } esle {
    update_post_meta($post_ID, "category", $feature, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry., update_post_meta...